# Hide out of stock products from woocommerce category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

After many research i got many solutions but all are not working for me or my website.

At category page at some pages products show less then 20 like 19 or 16...

I set Hide out of stock products from woocommerce setting page.

And Also used this code in theme funtions.php

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'iconic_hide_out_of_stock_products' );

function iconic_hide_out_of_stock_products( $q ) {

    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() || is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

if ( $outofstock_term = get_term_by( 'name', 'outofstock', 'product_visibility' ) ) {

    $tax_query = (array) $q->get('tax_query');
//$outofstock_term->term_taxonomy_id;
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
        'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
        'terms' => array( $outofstock_term->term_taxonomy_id ),
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    );

     $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );

}

    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'iconic_hide_out_of_stock_products' );

}
```

Please visit at my site and see.

```
https://www.waspsliving.dk/nyheder/page/71/
```